# Splitting up a pcm file into minute using ffmpeg long chunks

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, split

I have a large **pcm** file with about an hour's worth of data. I want to split it up into minute long chunks. Is there a way to **ffmpeg** to do that pr some other utility?

Basically going from `0 - 3600s` I want multiple files each going from `0 - 60s, 61-120s` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg's segment muxer does this.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -c copy -f segment -segment_time 60 out%d.wav
```

This will create `out0.wav, out1.wav, out2.wav` ... , each 60 seconds long.

If your input is raw PCM rather than WAV/AIFF, you'll need to manually set the input parameters e.g. `ffmpeg -f s16le -channels 2 -ar 48000 -i in.pcm ...`